# add_action into another add_action not working

Tags: plugins, php, actions

I have this little php code for wordpress. It doesn't work. I want to make one add_action under another add_action. But the add_action that is under, is not working!

```
function no_reminder() {
    echo "no_reminder function is active";
    add_action('admin_menu','no_reminder');

    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom');
function custom() {
    add_menu_page('settings', 'settings', '8', 'custom', 'customfunc');
}

function customfunc(){
    $wpp_rg = get_option('wpp_rg');
    if ($_POST['wpp_submit']):
        update_option('wpp_rg',$_POST['wpp_rg']);
    endif;
    $farzad = get_option('wpp_rg');
    /******************** IF1 ***********************/
    if ($farzad==1) {
        do_action('no_reminder');
        no_reminder();
        echo "If active";
    }
    if ($farzad==2) {
        echo "IF Not Active";
    }
/******************** IF1 ***********************/
?>
<div class="wrap">
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
        <th scope="row">test mode :</th>
        <td><p>
         <label>
                <input name="wpp_rg" type="radio" value="1" id="RadioGroup1_0" <?php echo ($farzad==1 ? 'checked="checked"' : '') ?> />
                active</label>
         <br />
         <label>
                <input name="wpp_rg" type="radio" value="2" id="RadioGroup1_1" <?php echo ($farzad==2 ? 'checked="checked"' : '') ?>/>
                not active</label>
         <br />
        </p></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><input type="submit" name="wpp_submit" value="save" class="button" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

?>
```

What should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred method of creating a settings page is to use the [WordPress Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

From your code example, it looks like it's too late to remove the `admin_notices` hook inside your callback in the `admin_menu` hook.

You should try to move the logic from the `customfunc()` callback into another callback activated from some earlier hook, for example  `admin_init`.

Additionally:

You are also calling the new admin menu page *settings*, but the user might confuse it with the existing *Settings* page.

The *User Levels* you have in one of the `add_menu_page()` input parameters, are deprecated, use instead some of the *Capabilites* mentioned [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

So instead use for example:

```
add_menu_page( 'My settings', 'My settings', 'manage_options', 'custom', 'customfunc' );
```

Comment: thanks, but now there is a problem, it's always do 'remove_action' , when i select "Not active" , it's still "Active ! "

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I agree that a lot of the OP's issues will probably resolve themselves once the OP starts using the Settings API correctly.

Comment: @birgire thanks for details and answer, but it's not working again. can u help more ?

Comment: @UserPHP **You** can help "more" by specifying what "it's not working again" is. This is vague at its best. Please come up with specific debug/error output and a really detailed description of assumptions vs. real world output.

Comment: @kaiser You are right, but i have enabled debug with this : `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and i have no error :) but that is not working :D

Comment: First, please read in Codex about debugging and `WP_DEBUG`. Second - as I already said - not working is _no_ proper problem or error description.

Comment: @kaiser thanks. You are right, i have also tested `WP_DEBUG` but still no errors ! i think i have a problem on setting the codes ! maybe i have to add some new code ...

Comment: While you are going through the settings API and the above suggestions, you might try to add something like this (untested) : http://pastebin.com/fcH4MV8r to your code snippet. I don't want to add this to the answer, since I think you should use the settings API ;-)

Comment: @birgire WOW ! Thanks dear birgire :X :X Really thanks :D Problem is solved. update the answere :) :X I will send you some reputation :D

Comment: thanks @UserPHP, glad to hear it worked. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: holy smoke, what happened to my reputation, it raised about +300 suddenly, don't understand it? did you put a bounty on this question?

Comment: @birgire i do this with anyone who helps me, +1 for your other answers ;)

Comment: I see, appreciate your thoughts and the vote on this answer, but please stop it on other questions, I would like to earn it through hard work. Could you down vote them back, thanks